# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int message in T-SQL code

Tags: type-conversion, int, sqldatatypes, ssms-2017

I have the following code:

```
     SELECT 
            ehrprg.ReportName 
           ,ehrprg.AnnualGoalServiceMinutes
           ,COUNT(DISTINCT ct.[ClientFK]) AS [UnduplicatedClients]

    FROM 
           [WH].[Fact].[EHRClinicalTransaction] ct
    INNER JOIN [Dimension].EHRProgram ehrprg ON 
                           ct.ProgramFK = ehrprg.WHID

    WHERE
          ehrprg.AnnualGoalServiceMinutes > 0

    GROUP BY
            ehrprg.ReportName 
           ,ehrprg.AnnualGoalServiceMinutes 

    ORDER BY
           ReportName
```

and result:

[image]

But I need it would have only one 'SM NV'(instead of 2) and one 'SM REACH' (instead of 3) rows in the **[ReportName]** column, summarizing **[ServiceMinutes]**

When I use **SUM(ehrprg.AnnualGoalServiceMinutes)** it gives me "**Arithmetic overflow error converting to datatype int**" error.

Then, I tried ,**SUM(CONVERT(BIGINT, ehrprg.AnnualGoalServiceMinutes))**, but getting the following:

[image]

It is still not grouping (not summarizing AnnualGoalServiceMinutes) and gives some values, I can't understand

My goal is to see instead of-

```
        ReportName   AnnualGoalServiceMin
        SM NV        197885
        SM NV        348654

        SM REACH     40000 
        SM REACH     80000
        SM REACH     380000
```

I expect the SUM of the AnnualGoalServiceMin:

```
       ReportName   AnnualGoalServiceMin
       SM NV        546539
       SN REACH     500000
```

Please, help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the source of the overflow error (it should not be happening based on the magnitude of the integers invovled), but I think what you need here is a second level of aggregation:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        ehrprg.ReportName,
        ehrprg.AnnualGoalServiceMinutes,
        COUNT(DISTINCT ct.[ClientFK]) AS UnduplicatedClients
   FROM [WH].[Fact].[EHRClinicalTransaction] ct
   INNER JOIN [Dimension].EHRProgram ehrprg
        ON ct.ProgramFK = ehrprg.WHID
   WHERE ehrprg.AnnualGoalServiceMinutes > 0
   GROUP BY ehrprg.ReportName, ehrprg.AnnualGoalServiceMinutes
)

SELECT
    ReportName,
    SUM(AnnualGoalServiceMinutes) AS AnnualGoalServiceMinutes,
    SUM(UnduplicatedClients) AS UnduplicatedClients
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    ReportName;
```

Comment: Sorry, I am confused... Why do I need this 2nd level of aggregation? Also, how exactly should I write this? When I paste your modified code, it gives an error                                                                                       "ncorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon."